# Opencv. How to track the velocity of a sediment

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a script to determine the settling velocity in a graduated cylinder. I made a timelapse video with intervals of 30 seconds. On the image you see on the left 3 pictures t0, and on the richt 3 pictures further in time. I want to determine the settling velocity but can't find a code to solve my problem.

[image: left 3 images t0, right t7]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# import numpy as np
cnt = []
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/Users/nite.mp4')


ret, frame1 = cap.read()
frame1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#hoogte,hoogte+ ..... breedte,breedte+
cropped1 = frame1[300:800, 920:1000]
cv2.imshow("cropped first frame", cropped1)

bg = None #achtergrond reference eerste frame

# Settings
interval = 5
active_line = None
frame_counter = 0
last_frame_number = 0

s_per_frame = 1 / 2  # FPS = 2
m_per_pixel = 0.11 / 264  # in meter afstand per pixel
distance = m_per_pixel * interval   #distance per measurement

velocities = list()
distances = list()

while(cap.isOpened()):
    contour_sum = 0
    ret, frame = cap.read()


    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cropped = frame[300:800, 920:1000]
    cv2.imshow('cropped',cropped)
        
    if bg is None:
        bg = cropped
        #bg = frame

    if active_line is None:
        active_line = cropped.shape[1] - 120
                
                
    # Haal nieuwe plaatje van eerste plaatje af
    subtracted = cv2.subtract(cropped, bg)
    cv2.imshow('subtracted',subtracted)
    # define a threshold, 128 is the middle of black and white in grey scale
    thresh = 50

    # assign blue channel to zeros 0 is black 255 is white
    ret, img_binary = cv2.threshold(subtracted, thresh, 255, 0)
    cv2.imshow('tresh',img_binary)      
    img_height = img_binary.shape[0]
        
    # canny = cv2.Canny(subtracted, 20,40)
    # cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
    # kernel = np.ones((5,5))
    # dilated = cv2.dolate()
         
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord ('d'):
        break
    if key == ord('p'):
        cv2.waitKey(-1)    


cap.release()
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How would you solve it without a program and what would be the answer please?

Comment: As I have pictures every 30 seconds.  Normally without a programme i would determine the distance the yellow/red line will travel and devide it by the the time. As seen on the picture there are big lines which correlate to a distance of 3.5 centimeters.

Comment: Do you control/run the experiments yourself? Could you make life easier for yourself by colouring the big lines differently so you could find them more simply? E.g. topmost big line red, second big line green, third big line yellow, fourth one cyan.

Comment: move the camera further away from the syringe/cylinder. put an illuminated wall or piece of paper behind the cylinder. fixing *how* your pictures are made is the best thing you can do. these pictures are unnecessarily hard to work with.

Comment: Moving the camera further away will reduce your parallax error... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax

Comment: Many thanks for your responses. I do control this experiment myself. These are the cropped pictures. https://photos.app.goo.gl/UNwPShV78RNUwqN16 is the real size photo. Actually I need a code to calculate the speed of the white area moving downwards. I cannot find out how to code this.